# What does it mean by separating the task from the thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading up on multi-threaded programming in Java.  In the java book it says separating the task from the thread is a preferred design.  I have no idea what this means.

From what I understand it is better to use implements Runnable instead of extending Threads.  I just don't understand why this is.

Why is implementing better then extending? And when would you use extending then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important principle in software design is separation of concerns: Every module/object/class/method should have only one well-defined responsibility.

The Thread class mixes two concerns:

- specifiying a sequence of steps to be executed (the Runnable)
- interacting with the runtime system to manage how to implement execution of that sequence (in this case by means of a dedicated CPU thread)

An application programmer should not need to concern himself with that second part: She should just need to write down a code path that she wants executed, i.e. implement a Runnable.

That Runnable can then be executed in a number of ways, for example by starting a new Thread, but also by giving it to an ExecutionService. This flexibility goes away when you hard-code your runnable into a Thread.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of `Runnable` is that you can pass a `Runnable` to things other than the `Thread` constructor. For instance, you can use them in conjunction with the new concurrency frameworks.

One reason you might extend `Thread` is if your task needs direct access to the `Thread` object that it's running in.

Answer (score 0):

Logically an IS-A relationship shouldn't deal with a concept of composition.

So, extending Thread Class are "useful" when you want to create a custom Thread, that benefit of all super methods or override certains methods => In this case for a Thread class, it's certainly useless for most cases.

Furthermore, extending Thread prevents you to extend a needed business class for instance whereas with an interface, you can still extends from the class you desire.

We always have to wonder if the new class NEED a concept or IS the concept.

You NEED Thread for Business class , so it's likely to separate it from all Threading notion => So Runnable is enough light for masking it.